# Object of class Login_Model could not be converted to string

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class Login_Model could not be converted to string
>
> Filename: models/login_model.php
>
> Line Number: 27

```
public function login() {
    //check user type

    $this->_table_name = 'tbl_employee_login';
    $this->_order_by = 'employee_login_id';
    $employee = $this->get_by(array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
         'password' => $this->$this->input->post('password'), LINE NUMBER 27
        'activate' => 1
    ), TRUE);
    /*employee*/
    $this->_table_name = 'driver';
    $this->_order_by = 'driver_id';

    $driver = $this->get_by(array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $this->$this->input->post('password'),
    ), TRUE);
    /*driver*/
    $this->_table_name = 'tbl_user';
    $this->_order_by = 'user_id';

    $admin = $this->get_by(array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $this->$this->input->post('password'),
            ), TRUE);
    if ($admin) {
        $data = array(
            'email' => $admin->email,
            'first_name' => $admin->first_name,
            'last_name' => $admin->last_name,
            'employee_id' => $admin->user_id,
            'loggedin' => TRUE,
            'user_type' => 1,
            'user_flag' => $admin->flag,
            'url' => 'admin/dashboard',
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    } elseif($employee) {

        if (count($employee)) {
            // Log in user
            $employee_id = $employee->employee_id;
            $this->_table_name = "tbl_employee"; //table name
            $this->_order_by = "employee_id";
            $user_info = $this->get_by(array('employee_id' => $employee_id), TRUE);

            $data = array(
                'email' => $employee->email,
                'employee_id' => $employee->employee_id,
                'user_name' => $user_info->first_name . '  ' . $user_info->last_name,
                'employee_login_id' => $employee->employee_login_id,
                'loggedin' => TRUE,
                'user_type' => 2,
                'url' => 'employee/dashboard',
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        }
    }
    elseif($driver){
        $data = array(
            'email' => $driver->email,
            'drive_id' => $driver->driver_id,
            'name' => $driver->name,
            'loggedin' => TRUE,
            'user_type' => 3,
            'url' => 'driver/dashboard',
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    }
}
```

can any one give me a solution to solve this Error. i try to login using admin user name and password but it show me this and more error like string convert

Comment: can you post your whole class ...you just posted a function.. so that i could find out line number 27

Comment: @Farsay, `'password' => $this->$this->input->post('password'), LINE NUMBER 27`

Comment: Why do you have `$this->$this`?

Comment: why do you have $this->$this->input->post('password'),  ($this 2 times) ... isnt it  just -  $this->input->post('password')

Comment: thank you every one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `typo` double `$this`

```
'password' => $this->$this->input->post('password'),
```

Change to

```
'password' =>$this->input->post('password'),
```

**Note :** And also `same mistake` in  many `other lines` too take care about that .

Comment: yes i will mark after website give me permission after 5 min

Comment: Cool :)  Glad to help you  :)

Answer (score 1):

it should be $this->input->post('password')

Answer (score 1):

you have typing mistakes which is $this->$this on 3 places in your code.